# Loop looping through last value in dictionary key instead of all values in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm very new to programming so bare with me.

I'm learning through a book "Python Crash Course: A hands-on, project-based Introduction to Programming"

I'm writing a code that involves making a dictionary, followed by looping a sentence about the items in the dictionary, then creating a loop that just prints the value of each key in the dictionary.

I got the first part done, however when writing the second loop it simply returns the value of the last key in the dictionary and loops it over multiple times instead of looping the individual values in the key. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
rivers = {'nile': 'egypt', 'amazon': 'south america',
    'mississipi': 'us', 'yangtze': 'china',
    'ganges': 'india',}
for river, rivers in rivers.items():
        print(f"The {river.title()} is in {rivers.title()}")
for river in rivers:
print(rivers)
```

Comment: You overwrite the definition of `rivers` in your first for loop: `for river, rivers in rivers.items():`. Use a different variable name, like `country`, in the for loop.

Comment: For every iteration of the `for` loop, the variables `river` and `rivers` get overridden with the next value from whatever `rivers.items()` was at the _start_ of the loop. They don't get cleared once the loop ends, and thus when you try to print `for river in rivers` later, the last value that the loop set it to is what you get. Be careful not to name two variables the same thing when they're near each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are rebinding the name `rivers` from the entire dictionary to an individual value in each iteration. After the first loop is done, `rivers` will point out to the last visited value in the dictionary.

You should be using a different name for one of the references. What about `country` per each value during the iteration?

```
rivers = {'nile': 'egypt', 'amazon': 'south america',
    'mississipi': 'us', 'yangtze': 'china',
    'ganges': 'india',}
for river, country in rivers.items():
    print(f"The {river.title()} is in {country.title()}")
for river in rivers:
    print(rivers)
```

**However**, I'm still not sure what is the purpose of the second loop. If you want to print the key, value pairs alone that can be done with the first loop.

```
for river, country in rivers.items():
    ...
    print(river, country)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I will be mindful of how I name my items, that makes sense thank you again! and the redundancy is just trivial exercises as the chapter i'm on is regarding dictionaries and loops so it helps me get the hang of writing code and learning the syntaxes.